# Identifying a prime number: Why only check for factors up to $\sqrt{N}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

My math professor told the class that

> For a positive integer $N$, if $N$ is not divisible by prime less than $|\sqrt{N}|$, then $N$ is prime.

For example, for $139$,  $12>|\sqrt{139}|>11$. But $139$ is not divisible by $2, 3, 5, 7, 11$ so $139$ is prime.

Why is it necessary that it has to be $\sqrt{N}$? Is the same property applicable for some other $f(N)$ (here $f(N)=\sqrt{N}$. I am asking if there is some other $f(N)$ besides that)?

Comment: If $n=pq$, then $p$ or $q$ is at least $\sqrt N$, since otherwise $pq<N$.  It's also true that if $N$ is not divisible by a prime less than $f(N)=N$ or $f(N)=\sqrt N+1, $ then $N$ is prime, but those are not as helpful

Comment: $f(N)=N$ is trivial but time consuming.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be $\sqrt{N}$. Obviously it could be $\sqrt{N}+1$ or any other function greater than or equal to it. In the other direction, you could make the function return $0$ if $N$ is prime or else $\sqrt{N}$, however, that’s not going to help you *find* primes. There might be a more practical alternative function but I doubt it, since for squares of primes it would seemingly have to be bounded below by the square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N=pq$, then $p$ or $q$ is at least $\sqrt{N}$, since otherwise $pq<N$.  That is why $f(N)=\sqrt{N}$ works.

It's also true that, if $N$ is not divisible by a prime less than $f(N)=N$ or $f(N)=\sqrt{N}+1, $

then $N$ is prime, but those are not as helpful.

Comment: So $f(N)=\sqrt{N}$ is the minimum?

Comment: if you took $f(N)$ less than $\sqrt N$, you would falsely conclude that $49$ is prime

Comment: @J.W. Tanner. As I pointed out, you could set $f(N)=0$ if $N$ is prime or else $f(N)=\sqrt{N}$. I doubt there’d be a function like it that wouldn’t be “cheating”, and clearly it couldn’t always be lower.

Comment: *Please, please* strive to organize dupes of FAQs, not exacerbate the problem by creating more such,.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=pq$. If $p=k\sqrt{N}$ where $k\in\mathbb{Q}^+$, then $q=\dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{k}$.

If $k=1$, clearly $\sqrt{N}$ is a factor of $N$.

If $k<1$, then $p<\sqrt{N}$, so there must be at least one factor of $N$ less than $\sqrt{N}$.

If $k>1$, then $q<\sqrt{N}$, so there must be at least one factor of $N$ less than $\sqrt{N}$.

Therefore, there always exists at leastone number less than or equal to $\sqrt{N}$ that divides $N$. So, if there is no such number, $N$ is definitely prime.

Hope this is clear. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Downvoters: MathSE says you should mention the reason for downvoting so that the post may be improved.